# ADL(2,2) modelling in R with differenced variables and lags

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, lag

I'm new to time series analysis and I am trying to model this relationship based on a very simple dataset containing only two time series: percentual changes of sales - **y**, regressed on the percentual change in purchases - **x** and a deterministic trend.

```
'data.frame':   98 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ time         : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ sales        : num  3.18 4.59 5.41 5.68 4.62 ...
 $ comppurchases: num  1.675 0.246 0.333 0.969 0.147 ...
```

The dataset is based on an example from a book, so I am trying to figure out the regression formula according to the output presented in the book. The author presented coefficients for y_(t-1), ∆y_t-1, x_t, ∆x_t, ∆x_t-1 and time as explanatory variables.

This would then be my equation:

> ∆y_t = a + φ*y_(t-1) + λ*∆y_t-1 + β*x_t + β1*∆x_t + β2*∆x_t-1 + + d*time + error

And the corresponding R syntax:

`regr <- dynlm(d(sales) ~ L(sales,1)+L(d(sales))+ comppurchases +d(comppurchases)+L(d(comppurchases)) + time, data=df)`

The problem is, whenever I run the syntax, I get this error:

> Error: all(sapply(args, function(x) is.zoo(x) || !is.plain(x) ||
>   (is.plain(x) &&  .... is not TRUE

Is there anything wrong with my syntax? What am I missing here? I'm not even sure if the problem is with the syntax or with my understanding of the regression formula.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Need to show at least str(df) and ... please do not answer in the comments.

Comment: Okay I added it @42-

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dynlm/dynlm.pdf) of dynlm package, it says that you need to have your columns in a time-series format to use the built-in dynlm functions "d" and "L".

> All new formula functions require that their arguments are time series
>   objects (i.e., "ts" or "zoo").

First, I assumed that sales and purchases were raw data and not percentage changes. If this is not true, then you can adapt this to your needs.

The function worked after creating new column the % change in sales, "sales_delta" and using that in the regression instead of the built in function "d(data, lag)". I couldn't get this function to work.

I tried replicating the results with the base "lm" function after creating the columns manually and the regression coefficients are the same. One difference was in the data argument. For lm, I had to specify to ignore the first 2 columns, which had NA values, while the dynlm package has the default method of omitting rows with NA values.

```
time = seq(1,11,1)
sales = c(3.18, 4.59, 5.41, 5.68, 4.62, 5.08, 6.02, 6.15, 5.99, 6.03, 6.05)
purch = c(1.675, 0.246, 0.333, 0.969, 0.147, 0.258, 0.65, 0.85, 0.25, 0.11, 0.25)
require(zoo)

df = data.frame(time = time, sales = sales, purch = purch)
df$sales = zoo(df$sales)
df$purch = zoo(df$purch)

df$sales_lag1 = NA
df$sales_lag1[2:nrow(df)] = df$sales[1:nrow(df)-1]
df$sales_delta = df$sales/df$sales_lag1 - 1
df$sales_delta_lag1 = NA
df$sales_delta_lag1[3:nrow(df)] = df$sales_delta[2:(nrow(df)-1)]

df$purch_lag1 = NA
df$purch_lag1[2:nrow(df)] = df$purch[1:nrow(df)-1]
df$purch_delta = df$purch/df$purch_lag1 - 1
df$purch_delta_lag1 = NA
df$purch_delta_lag1[3:nrow(df)] = df$purch_delta[2:(nrow(df)-1)]

mod_base = lm(sales_delta ~ sales_lag1 + sales_delta_lag1 + purch +      purch_delta + purch_delta_lag1 + time, data = df[-c(1:2),])
summary(mod_base)

require(dynlm)
mod_dynlm = dynlm(sales_delta ~ L(sales,1) + L(sales_delta,1) + purch +  purch_delta + L(purch_delta,1) + time, data = df)


#Check if results are similar
mod_base$coefficients == mod_dynlm$coefficients
```

Hope this helps. In general, I would recommend sticking to the base functions and using a package only when required.

Comment: Interesting. I would have thought that including both lag(sales) and lag(sales_delta) in predicting sales_delta might be creating an over-determined situation. Also seemed really surprising to create zoo objects as separate entities inside a dataframe structure.